# Configure Mobile Center Connector for ADB devices full plug'n'play?

Tags: mobile, microfocus-mobile-center

There is a known issue of ADB instability - the ADB bridge can disconnect the devices for few seconds.
How to instruct Mobile Center to perform full plug-n-play operation while this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

1. edit the application.properties file to the classes folder of the service: 
   located on \connector\jetty\webapps\hp4m-connector\WEB-INF\classes\application.properties
2. edit or add the following property:
   plug.n.play.android.quickConnect.in.millis=1000
3. restart the service